# android - connect android application to Amazon Web Services (AWS) database tables.

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I am creating an application where I want to connect my app to AWS MySQL Database table.

I bought an AWS server for integrating my android application with AWS web services. I used MySQL Work-bench for creating database and tables. I connected the  MySQL Workbench database to the AWS server,  as I saw the server status and it was running fine.

Also, as stated in the documentation at AWS website, I downloaded 'awsconfiguration.json' file in the 'raw' folder in my application. I added the below code for connecting my application to AWS.

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
                Log.i("YourMainActivity", "AWSMobileClient is instantiated and you are connected to AWS!");
            }
}).execute();
```

It showed me in the Logcat that, `I/AWSMobileClient: Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully.`

Also, I would like to convey that I created a simple user's table with some columns on MySQL Workbench (which is connected to AWS server), but it is not reflecting anywhere on the AWS dashboard.

Now, I want some serious help in firstly, displaying my Database and user's table at AWS servers, and secondly, how to get response, i.e., data from user's table into my application.

I am using Android Studio and using language Java for my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting in AWSForums may provide you more help.

Comment: i checked all the documentation, was alot confusing